# What is the line cutting benzene ring?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

There is a line cutting benzene ring what is that called.

Comment: The line is just a bond. You draw it like that when you are unsure or don't care where exactly it should connect to the benzene ring.

Comment: Just a clarification to @IvanNeretin's comment: It's when it may be of any configuration -- ortho-, meta- or para-substituted.

Comment: Related: [Structural representation of substituted benzene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/54765/7951) and [For a benzene shown in a skeletal structure, what does a substituent to the center of the ring mean?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/114602/7951)

Comment: The depiction at start is wrong as for there is only one monosubstituted benzene. Avoid that representation.